# dynamic navbar thymeleaf HTML

Tags: html, thymeleaf

i generate a dynamic navbar. If one reference ${xn} will not return a value from the controller then no choice will be rendered in the navbar.

But I think it's a bad coding style like I have it right now. Moreover if I have N elements I accordingly need N placeholders.

That is why I would actually prefer a loop that receives and render the available navbar elements from the controller.

But I am not allowed to add a

```
<tr th:each="String: ${navbarElements}">
```

anywhere.

**Here my working solution so far:**

```
  <div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="start.html">
        <h2>Chose what you want to trade</h2>
        <label>
            <select th:name="Products" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple">
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="first" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
                <option th:text="${first}"></option>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="second" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
                <option th:text="${second}"></option>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="third" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
                <option th:text="${third}"></option>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="forth" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
                <option th:text="${forth}"></option>
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="fith" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
                <option th:text="${fith}"></option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <button th:type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**and a pseudo solution which is not working**

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="start.html">
        <h2>Chose what you want to trade</h2>
        <label>
            <select th:name="Products" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple">
                <!--/*@thymesVar id="first" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
                <tr th:each="product : ${productList}">
                <option th:text="${product}"></option>
                </tr>
            </select>
        </label>
        <button th:type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the problem... is it just because you can't surround `<option>`s with `<tr>`s?  Why don't you put the th:each on the option like this: `<option th:each="product : ${productList}" th:text="${product}"></option>`

Comment: Uh i didnt know that this syntax is allowed ( I am new to HTML ) Thank you a lot. Could you answer in regular that you get the bounty for answering =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `th:each` (and most thymeleaf attributes) to any html tag.  Just move the `th:each` to the `<option>` tag, like this:

```
<option th:each="product : ${productList}" th:text="${product}"></option>
```